# How can I fill whole column based on each of its row datas using IF function?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htk4q.png)

*So the "•" is acting like a tick mark. The grey-colored font is the RESULT that I want to have whenever I input a tick mark in whichever column.*

For example:
1. If I tick the "B" only, the "Package" (which is in this case is cell F3) will automatically be filled with "Cheapest".
2. If I tick all of the columns: A,B,1,2,3, the "Package" will automatically be filled with "Full Package".
3. and so on.

If possible can someone help me with the VBA Code because my skill in VBA is still not that good and I cannot use manual IF function since it'll be too long.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) The relation between the input ("•") and the contents of the result column F is not well defined. (2) It is not certain that you need VBA to achieve this kind of things. Simple spreadsheet functions can do the job in many cases.

Comment: @FDavidov (1) The problem is the real file is up to thousands of rows and copying manual IF function is just going to make the file heavier. (2) The function itself is up to 4 rows if using manual IF function. (3) So should I change the ("•") with something else?

Comment: (1) "Heavier": So? "Copying": If the function is phrased correctly, you simply **DRAG** the cell with the function or select the cell, copy it, select the full range of the target cells and paste (9 seconds to complete the operation). (2) "4 rows of formula": So? (3) You need to define the result for column F for each combination of marks in the other cells of the row.

Comment: @FDavidov in the IF function I use ISBLANK function. Is it because I use ("•") that the result is compromised? For example: if I type on cell F3 =ISBLANK(E3) the result is TRUE. But if i type =ISBLANK(C3:E3), the result is FALSE. Therefore resulting in my IF formula to be faulty.

Comment: No. "•" is a character like any other so ISBLANK would return `FALSE` if such a character is found. My point is that you have columns A to E which can contain that character, and (obviously) different combinations of contents in columns A-E should generate different values for F, right? So, my question is: **what are the rules?**

Comment: @FDavidov so this is my formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A2:E2),"Cancelled Purchase",IF(AND(ISBLANK(A2:B2),NOT(ISBLANK(C2:E2))),"Flower Package",IF(AND(ISBLANK(C2:E2),NOT(ISBLANK(A2:B2))),"Chocolate Package",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:E2)),"Full Package",""))))` and that's not the full of it. But the result showed "Full Package" on all cells in column F which is why I want to try whether VBA will generate a different answer or not. Is my formula faulty? I'm sorry to have bothered you with my questions.

Comment: It doesn't look like `ISBLANK` is working as expected; `ISBLANK(A1:A2)` returns TRUE as expected, but `ISBLANK(A1:B1)` returns FALSE. I.e. not working across a row, but working fine down a column.

Comment: Correction: on your example, `ISBLANK(A2:A3)` is expected to return TRUE, and does return TRUE. `ISBLANK(A4:B4)` returns FALSE, but should return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Does this provide the functionality you're after?

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(E2)),"Cancelled Purchase",IF(AND(AND(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2)),NOT(AND(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(E2)))),"Flower Package",IF(AND(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2))),AND(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(E2))),"Chocolate Package","Full Package")))
```

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate your answer. I've been trying to avoid to use that formula since I'd have long formula for only 1 scenario. I'll try to find another way. If I still cannot find it, I'll probably use your way. Once again, thank you! :D